# How to set a dynamic path for ZipArchive addFile

Tags: laravel, storage, filepath, php-ziparchive, laravel-storage

## EDIT

### Problem solved. Had to update my filesystems config.

I want to create a zip file including all invoices which have been generated before. The problem is, if I am trying to do it with laravels storage `url()` or `get()` function, ZipArchive can not find the files.

I tried to solve it with `storage_path()`, `->url()`, `->get()` but none of them worked. It only works if I am typing the path to the files.

This is how it looks right now and it works.

```php
$invoiceZipFileName = Carbon::now()->toDateString() . "_invoices.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($invoiceZipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$files->each(function ($item, $key) use ($zip, $disk) {
    $zip->addFile("storage/invoices/" . $item, $item);
});
$zip->close();
```

What I want to achieve is something like that:

```php
$invoiceZipFileName = Carbon::now()->toDateString() . "_invoices.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($invoiceZipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$files->each(function ($item, $key) use ($zip, $disk) {
    $zip->addFile($disk->get($item), $item);
});
$zip->close();
```

or:

```php
$invoiceZipFileName = Carbon::now()->toDateString() . "_invoices.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($invoiceZipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$files->each(function ($item, $key) use ($zip, $disk) {
    $zip->addFile($disk->url($item), $item);
});
$zip->close();
```

or:

```php
$invoiceZipFileName = Carbon::now()->toDateString() . "_invoices.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($invoiceZipFileName, ZipArchive::CREATE);
$files->each(function ($item, $key) use ($zip, $disk) {
    $zip->addFile(storage_path("invoices") . "/" . $item, $item);
});
$zip->close();
```

These are the error messages (each was in another case, they don't occur together) I get:

```
exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\Exception\FileNotFoundException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\invoicing\vendor\symfony\http-foundation\File\File.php"
line: 36
message: "The file "2019-10-02_invoices.zip" does not exist"
```

```
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\invoicing\app\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\InvoiceController.php"
line: 211
message: "ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file: No error"
```

++++ EDIT ++++
Problem solved. Had to update my filesystems config.

Answer (score 1):

- Using the below link setup Zipper package into your laravel project.

  https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper
- after completion of Zipper package setup use the below code into your respected controller.

  $files = glob($image_dir_media . $file_new_name);

  $date = new DateTime();

  $zip = $date->format('Y-m-d') . '_invoices.zip';

  \Zipper::make(public_path() . '/media/' . $zip)->add($files)->close();

Thanks
PHPanchal

Comment: That's the reason, why I want to avoid using it: ```I haven't updated this package in a long time except merging PRs. The last time I was using this package was with PHP5. I archived the repository for the reason that I am no longer working with PHP (we all have to move on sometimes) and have no time to take proper care of it anymore.```

Comment: Have you check with update composer command in project?
You develop this module during PHP5 was running but currently PHP7 is going on so should have to update with version and given package url will take few mins for setup and will work good.

Comment: Still don't want to use an outdated package which is not supported anymore.

Comment: Yes, Thats good things for use updated versions but this one is not outdated we can use for now. **https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper** You will get more in details with given url.